# Set the Default Date of WPF Date Picker to Current Date

Tags: wpf, datepicker

I have a WPF Datagrid in which one of the columns is a Date Column.

So i have used a DataTemplateColumn as Follows

```
<my:DataGridTemplateColumn
    CellTemplate="{StaticResource EffDateDateTimePickerControl}"
    CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource addrEffDate}"
    Header="Effective Date"/>
```

And in my Resource File i have written the following code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type my:Calendar}" x:Key="CalenderControlTemplate">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="my:Calendar" >
                <my:CalendarItem Name="myCalendarItem" 
                                 Background="White" 
                                 BorderBrush="Black"
                                 BorderThickness="1"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style> 

<DataTemplate x:Key="EffDateDateTimePickerControl">
    <Label x:Name="lblEffDate" Content="{Binding effectiveDate,Mode=TwoWay}" ></Label>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="addrEffDate">
    <my:DatePicker x:Name="dpEffDate" Text="{Binding Path=effectiveDate,Mode=TwoWay}"
                   SelectedDate="{Binding Now}" DisplayDateStart="{Binding Now}"
                   CalendarStyle="{DynamicResource CalenderControlTemplate}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

The problem is when i click on the DatePicker control the default date is set to 1/1/0001?

How can i set my datepicker to set to the current Date.

Answer (score 19):

Unless you have a property in your `DataContext` called `Now`, your `Bindings` will fail.  Instead, you should be using the `{x:Static}` syntax like so:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="addrEffDate">
    <my:DatePicker x:Name="dpEffDate" Text="{Binding Path=effectiveDate,Mode=TwoWay}"
                   SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" DisplayDateStart="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"
                   CalendarStyle="{DynamicResource CalenderControlTemplate}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Since `DateTime` isn't in the standard XAML namespace, you need to add a xmlns declaration to the root element:

```
<UserControl xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" ...
```

Comment: That should work, but if it doesn't, you can try doing {Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, Mode=OneTime}

Comment: I need it to bind to my Class. this is a new object in a new row, so how would it work ?

Comment: You can just bind directly to your class's property. If it is a new row in the DataGrid, your class won't have been created yet, so in that case you may have to supply a FallbackValue to the Binding, which can be the static DateTime.Today.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to replace

```
DisplayDateStart
```

with

```
DisplayDate
```

Because [`DisplayDateStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydatestart(VS.95).aspx): (from the MSDN)

> Gets or sets the first date to be displayed.

not the date to display.

Answer (score 0):

On top of [Abe Heidebrecht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9268/abe-heidebrecht)'s Answer I am providing an example. I think Abe's answer is correct.  I had the same issue with new object and class binding and solved the problem in the way mentioned below:

```
 get
 {
  return (ClassDate - DateTime.MinValue).TotalDays == 0 ? DateTime.Now :ClassDate;
 }
```

cheers :)