# WPF DatePicker, display todays date with binding to property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker

*This is a possible duplicate of [Set the Default Date of WPF Date Picker to Current Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662506/set-the-default-date-of-wpf-date-picker-to-current-date) but I have tried the code from the question and it doesn't work, hopefully I am missing something simple*

OK as the question states, I want to display the current date when the view loads, however, I have the SelectedDate property bounded to a property of mine, and I dont think you can use "Text" because the property that I am binding to is a DateTime property. yes, I could do a convert in the model but XAML (I think) should be able to do this for me.

OK I know what is the problem, the date is coming out "01/01/0001" because of course, its binding to my property which is defaulted to 01/01/0001, so I guess I will need to do some C# code in my property to say if its 01/01/0001, use DateTime.Now and if not, use the property.

The XAML

```
    <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                DisplayDate="{x:Static System:DateTime.Now}"
                SelectedDate="{Binding AvailableFrom, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Margin="139,58,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="120"/>
```

Am happy to delete this after if the big reps think it is a duplicate,

What I did to resolve...

```
     get
     {

         if (m_AvailableFrom == DateTime.MinValue)
             return DateTime.Now;

        return m_AvailableFrom;
     }
```

Cheers for the help

Comment: Answers, even from the OP, go in the answers section. Please remove the answer from the question then post it as an answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I personally would just assign `DateTime.Now` to the `AvailableFrom` property in the ViewModel code.

If you want to use XAML though, one option is to make the `AvailableFrom` property a `DateTime?` (nullable DateTime) rather than a `DateTime`. Then the default value is null rather than "01/01/0001".

Then, in your XAML you can use

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

<DatePicker
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    SelectedDate="{Binding
        Path=AvailableFrom,
        Mode=TwoWay,
        TargetNullValue={x:Static System:DateTime.Now}}"
    Margin="139,58,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="120" />
```

and the UI will display the current date anytime that `AvailableFrom` is null.

Comment: Hi Josh, this is what I have done, but in the Model, I will past code above, cheers

Comment: `Unknown build error, 'Key cannot be null. ...` I have no idea what this means... <DatePicker Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=StartDate, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue={x:Static System:DateTime.Now}}"/>

Comment: "DateTime is not supported in WPF." -- .net core 3.1

Answer (score 3):

The MSDN link for the SelectedDate property below shows it as nullable. I think instead of returning DateTime.Now just return null if it isn't set and I suspect like other controls with nullable fields, it will simply display nothing.

[DatePicker.SelectedDate MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -3):

```
<DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left"                 
        SelectedDate="{Binding AvailableFrom, Mode=TwoWay}"
        DisplayDate="{Binding DateTime.Now}"                
        Margin="139,58,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="120"/>
```

*Use DisplayDate after SelectedDate

mark if this useful thanks!